# Write Form Field From MikTex (via Pandoc) which iTextSharp Can Parse

Tags: miktex, pandoc

I'm doing some tests with `iTextSharp` to see it would work to automate a workflow I have. So, I am using `Pandoc` to generate some `pdf`s from `markdown`. But when I generate the files `iTextSharp` doesn't recognize the fields I have generated. It recognizes the fields in a different `pdf` I didn't create so I figure it is something that I am doing wrong.

**Solution**:

I guess I needed the form wrapper around it:

```
\begin{Form}

My field: \underline{\TextField[name=AField]{}}

\end{Form}
```

---

So, I start with this code in `Test.md`:

```
My field: \underline{\TextField[name=AField]{}}
```

If I use this command `pandoc -s .\Test.md -o Test.tex` to generate the `tex` file I get this result:

```
... see pre code below if this part of the latex file matter to you

\begin{document}

My field: \underline{\TextField[name=AField]{}}

\end{document}
```

Of course, I use this command `pandoc -s .\Test.md -o Test.pdf` to actually generate the `pdf`. Should I be using a different command to generate the `TextField`?

Code generated in `tex` file not included above for brevity:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode=true}{hyperref} % options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provides euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage[]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

% set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother


\date{}
```

Note: I asked [this question over on `StackOverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102029/write-form-field-from-miktex-via-pandoc-which-itextsharp-can-parse) but it is probably better here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I needed the form wrapper around it:

```
\begin{Form}

My field: \underline{\TextField[name=AField]{}}

\end{Form}
```